# Apache: RewriteRule suddenly stopped working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The path to my page is like wamp/www/a/b/c. In the last "c" Folder there is a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Until today, it worked, it redirected all calls to `localhost/a/b/c/path1/path2` to `localhost/a/b/c/index.php?p=path1/path2`. But today no more - all calls like `localhost/a/b/c/something` are redirected to localhost start page. I don't know why. I made a quick workaround changing last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ a/b/c/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any idea how to fix this (not to use the path in .htaccess file).

I haven't changed any server configs last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `RewriteBase` is incorrect. It should reflect the relative path from `DocumentRoot`. Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/b/c/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```